# jQuery .append() orders tags incorrectly?

Tags: jquery

There are other questions about append, but this is specifically about tag order. The function works fine for content, but seems to close tags before it opens new ones. In this code the words are placed correctly but the p tag is not within the span tag.

html:

```
<div></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("div").append('<span>begin');
        $("div").append('<p>middle</p>');
        $("div").append('end</span> ');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dpXv2/1

I want to use a loop to create multiple p's inside the span, how can I get around this?

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/dpXv2/3/ This should be a little clearer, and I removed the p tag.

Comment: Spans can't contain p elements.

Comment: Try this, `$("div").append('<span>begin<p>middle</p>end</span>');`. And again, `p` cannot be child of `span`

Comment: @Jashwant That would work, but I need to add loops to generate the content, this example is just stripped down to illustrate the problem

Comment: Duplicate of this question where I have written a detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498057/how-to-prevent-jquery-append-function-from-automatically-closing-a-p-with/21502950

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks, didn't see that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the p's to the span.
for example

```
$("div").append('<span>begin</span>');
$("div span").append('<p>middle</p>');
$("div span").after('end');
```

This is because the append adds the full tag when you add your first span.

EDIT:
My mistake, the after puts the 'end; text after the span - obviously.  You could use:

```
$("div span").html($("div span").html()+'end');
```

instead

Comment: Ok, this works, but it's going to be a little more cumbersome; is there a way to not have it auto-complete the tag?

Comment: Not that I know of, it looks like the browser is even auto completing incomplete tags added using .html()

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working fine.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Depending on the browser, they sometimes add closing tags to the page if

- There is no closing tag
- The tag within the parent is not allowed within that particular parent tag

Furthermore, I don't think you can put a `p` within a `span`, but you can put a `span` within a `p`.

`span` is meant to be used within `p` tags for any styling pertaining to that piece of code.